# Using particle physics math model to simulate simplest life

Tags: atomic-physics, computational-physics, simulations, biophysics, biology

We still don't know many thing going inside living cells so I'm wondering whether it's possible to create a math/computer model operating on basic known particles (or higher level composite particles to simplify the process), atom/formula bonds in order to simulate simplest life forming (given all the  conditions  for it to form) and study processes going inside it.
I see it as a vector model iterating over and over, applying forces to particles given their current state. After an unimaginably big number of iterations we would have simplest life form ready for tick by tick analysis, so we can understand biological processes better.

So the question is - is our understanding of particle physics capable of simulating an environment for life to evolve?

This question was already [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145811/) around six years ago, but I'm sure by now, there were many new researches and discoveries made, so I hope to get new answers.

Comment: Have you thought about how many atoms there are in a typical cell, and compared that with computer memory capacities and processing speeds?

Comment: @G.Smith I understand the difficulty of such model in terms of computational power required and I hope that this is the smallest problem we are facing now. With distributed computing systems I believe it is possible to achieve desired result. At least in future if not now. And we don't have to simulate whole cell, an organelle is a good start. This work describes 100-million atom simulation https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3365009
Haven't gone in full details with this article yet, but looks promising

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145811/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm mentioning this topic in my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we fully simulate molecular physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145811/)