# Can we calculate everything with an exact theory?

Tags: theory-of-everything

This question is not opinion based:

If we have found the fundamental theory of how our universe works and we have no limitation for our Supercomputer:

Could we then calculate everything/ every phenomenon we observe?

I read about the spectral gap problem: it has been shown [in 2015, that we cant calculate the gap.](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015Natur.528..207C/abstract) Even if we have an exact theory.

And what is with emergent systems, could we calculate them with our correct theory and supercomputer - or is this also not always possible?

Comment: I strongly believe that whatever mathematical foundation we base such a theory would _always_ be an approximation of real life. Moreover, either such a theory does not exist, or it as useless as `1=1`.

Comment: In this gedankenexperiment this theory is exact/correct

Comment: You mean predicting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is limited computational capacity a fundamental obstacle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/626319/is-limited-computational-capacity-a-fundamental-obstacle)

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything

Comment: Such an idea is based on the fallacious idea that nature is completely deterministic.  There are many examples, from quantum mechanics to chaos theory, that say otherwise.

Comment: @DavidWhite exactly what I thought. Even simple classical physics can be non-deterministic.

Comment: @Shing, do you have an example? If the initial values are known, classical physics is always deterministic as far as I know

Comment: @nuemlouno as long as the conditions of uniqueness theorem doesn't hold, then classical physics doesn't have to be deterministic. An example is Norton's dome.